# Can I save file to a directory in the app (not the document directory) at run time?

Tags: ios, sandbox

I have an iOS application that is seeded with data 1.json in the /resource folder. At runtime, i want to replace 1.json and save it in /resource folder again. I'm new to iOS app development, is this possible or do I have to save it to document folder?

Comment: The application's bundle is readonly.

Answer (score 0):

No, It is not possible. You bundle is read only.